# Freeing space in /boot, what images can I remove?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I need some advice regarding what images are safe to remove

I'm using 100% of boot and it's impossible to update using apt-get now so fixing this would be ideal.

Here's a list of the images I've got installed, it looks like some of them can be safely removed (where desired=r) but I haven't had to manually remove images before so and advice would be great.

```
mervyn@todhchai:/boot$ dpkg -l linux-image-\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                                                 Version                                         Architecture                                    Description
+++-====================================================================================-===============================================-===============================================-==============================================================================================================================================================================
un  linux-image-3.0                                                                      <none>                                          <none>                                          (no description available)
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                                                        3.13.0-24.47                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic                                                        3.13.0-27.50                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic                                                        3.13.0-29.53                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic                                                        3.13.0-30.55                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic                                                        3.13.0-32.57                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic                                                        3.13.0-33.58                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic                                                        3.13.0-34.60                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic                                                        3.13.0-35.62                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic                                                        3.13.0-36.63                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic                                                        3.13.0-37.64                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic                                                        3.13.0-39.66                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic                                                        3.13.0-40.69                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-41-generic                                                        3.13.0-41.70                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic                                                        3.13.0-43.72                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic                                                        3.13.0-44.73                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic                                                        3.13.0-46.79                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic                                                        3.13.0-48.80                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic                                                        3.13.0-49.83                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic                                                        3.13.0-51.84                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic                                                        3.13.0-52.86                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic                                                        3.13.0-53.89                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic                                                        3.13.0-54.91                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-55-generic                                                        3.13.0-55.94                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic                                                        3.13.0-57.95                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic                                                        3.13.0-58.97                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic                                                        3.13.0-59.98                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic                                                        3.13.0-61.100                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic                                                        3.13.0-62.102                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic                                                        3.13.0-63.103                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic                                                        3.13.0-65.106                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic                                                        3.13.0-66.108                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic                                                        3.13.0-67.110                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic                                                        3.13.0-68.111                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-70-generic                                                        3.13.0-70.113                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-71-generic                                                        3.13.0-71.114                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic                                                        3.13.0-73.116                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-74-generic                                                        3.13.0-74.118                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-76-generic                                                        3.13.0-76.120                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic                                                        3.13.0-77.121                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-79-generic                                                        3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-83-generic                                                        3.13.0-83.127                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-85-generic                                                        3.13.0-85.129                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-86-generic                                                        3.13.0-86.130                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                                                  3.13.0-24.47                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic                                                  3.13.0-27.50                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic                                                  3.13.0-29.53                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic                                                  3.13.0-30.55                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic                                                  3.13.0-32.57                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-33-generic                                                  3.13.0-33.58                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic                                                  3.13.0-34.60                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic                                                  3.13.0-35.62                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic                                                  3.13.0-36.63                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic                                                  3.13.0-37.64                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic                                                  3.13.0-39.66                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic                                                  3.13.0-40.69                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-41-generic                                                  3.13.0-41.70                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic                                                  3.13.0-43.72                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic                                                  3.13.0-44.73                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic                                                  3.13.0-46.79                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic                                                  3.13.0-48.80                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic                                                  3.13.0-49.83                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic                                                  3.13.0-51.84                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic                                                  3.13.0-52.86                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic                                                  3.13.0-53.89                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic                                                  3.13.0-54.91                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-55-generic                                                  3.13.0-55.94                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic                                                  3.13.0-57.95                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic                                                  3.13.0-58.97                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic                                                  3.13.0-59.98                                    amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic                                                  3.13.0-61.100                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic                                                  3.13.0-62.102                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic                                                  3.13.0-63.103                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic                                                  3.13.0-65.106                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic                                                  3.13.0-66.108                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic                                                  3.13.0-67.110                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic                                                  3.13.0-68.111                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-70-generic                                                  3.13.0-70.113                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-71-generic                                                  3.13.0-71.114                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic                                                  3.13.0-73.116                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-74-generic                                                  3.13.0-74.118                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-76-generic                                                  3.13.0-76.120                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic                                                  3.13.0-77.121                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-79-generic                                                  3.13.0-79.123                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-83-generic                                                  3.13.0-83.127                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-85-generic                                                  3.13.0-85.129                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-86-generic                                                  3.13.0-86.130                                   amd64                                           Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic
```

**Answered:**

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will remove all un-needed packages, including un-needed kernal images

Comment: You may wish to type `sudo apt-get -s autoremove` first, to make sure that you won't lose anything critical (such as your current kernel). Also, adding `--purge` to the live command will get rid of the superfluous configuration files.

Comment: Good point, I updated my question to reflect the proper functionality of autoremove.

Comment: For the record, I prefer to use `synaptic` for removing old versions. If you select displaying `Installed` packages and filter on `3.13.0` this will show all the installed kernels and ancillary packages (headers, tools, etc). Sort by `Installed Version` to group all the updates together, and you can then use the mouse with the `Shift` / `Ctrl` keys to select the redundant releases. Now you can right-click and select `Mark for Complete Removal`: click `Apply` to complete the process.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  As a Q&A site, questions should be just questions and solutions should go in answers.  Self-answering is encouraged.  The site is a knowledge base, with posts indexed, and answers are where people look for solutions.  Moving your answer to an answer post will enable people to find it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short howto

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-delete-old-kernel-images-command/

Basically you should run

sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic

But be careful not to remove your current kernel!

Comment: I completely forgot, apt-get autoremove would fix this *d'oh* Thanks a mil for the link, it reminded me